# Why I can access Core Data entities in viewDidAppear, but not in viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a UITableViewController subclass and when I try to fetch some entities from viewDidLoad, I get an empty array. But when I use the same code in viewDidAppear I get those entities! How's that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a `NSFetchedResultsController`? That is the recommended (and easiest) way to populate a table view with Core Data. You would not have to care about the time of the fetch because the results controller would managed that for you.

Without the FRC you are responsible for populating the table. Depending on your setup, i.e. how you create the view controller, it is possible that all necessary parts (including the managed object context, or a data array, or your table view itself) are not fully loaded yet by the time `viewDidLoad` runs. Typically, `viewDidLoad` is best used for view controllers that are loaded from a nib or storyboard. You provide the necessary properties in `prepareForSegue:` or some such method, and they will be available to `viewDidLoad:`.

Still, you should go with the FRC. It will do the fetch more or less lazily through the datasource methods. That would also be the best option for performance and memory management.

Comment: Right now I'm using a custom class to fetch those entities for me, change them a bit and rearrange them in an NSArray with NSDictionaries (because I'm adding some additional properties to the entities, just for presentation purposes). In that case, is it still appropriate to use FRC?

Comment: Were all the buggy parts of NSFetchedResultsController fixed? Historically, it had problems.

Comment: I have not discovered any bugs in FRC. Yes, a FRC is the appropriate way, even if you want to combine with other information. A custom class to fetch seems to be disadvantageous in terms of memory management.